# Docker replace solr config

Tags: docker, solr, copy

I have small docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  solr:
    image: solr:8.6.2
    container_name: solr
    environment:
      SOLR_JAVA_HOME: /usr/local/openjdk-11
      SOLR_JAVA_MEM: "-Xms1024m -Xmx8192m"
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - "-c"
      - "precreate-core document; exec solr -f"
    command: "cp ./solr/db-data-config.xml /var/solr/data/document/conf/db-data-config.xml"
```

First I create core - document
Then I want replace default confgiuration

*db-data-config
managed-schema
solrconfig*

In this path - /var/solr/data/document/conf

What is the best way to do this?